# RuntimeError: RUNTIME ERROR: undefined external variable: jsonlines_embedding_format

Tags: python, allennlp

When I run the command, ant got this issue. The version of the  allennlp is 0.9.

`allennlp train /root/code/python/share/scidocs/data/recomm/train_similar_papers_model.json -s /root/code/python/share/scidocs/data/recomm-tmp --include-package scidocs.recommender`

And the key message of the train_similar_papers_model.json is here:

```
local stringToBool(s) =
  if s == "true" then true
  else if s == "false" then false
  else error "invalid boolean: " + std.manifestJson(s);
local EMBEDDINGS_PATH = std.extVar("EMBEDDINGS_PATH");
local CUDA_DEVICE = std.parseInt(std.extVar("CUDA_DEVICE"));
local EMBEDDINGS_DIM = std.parseInt(std.extVar("EMBEDDINGS_DIM"));
local PAPER_METADATA_PATH = std.extVar("PAPER_METADATA_PATH");
local TRAIN_PATH = std.extVar("TRAIN_PATH");
local VALID_PATH = (if std.extVar("VALID_PATH")!="" then std.extVar("VALID_PATH") else null);
local TEST_PATH = std.extVar("TEST_PATH");
local PROP_SCORE_PATH = std.extVar("PROP_SCORE_PATH");
{
    "random_seed": 7,
    "pytorch_seed": 7,
    "numpy_seed": 7,
    "dataset_reader": {
      "type": "simclick_data_reader",
      "paper_features_path": PAPER_METADATA_PATH,
      "paper_embeddings_path": EMBEDDINGS_PATH,
      "max_results_per_query": 10,
      "jsonlines_embedding_format": stringToBool(std.extVar('jsonlines_embedding_format'))
    },

    ....
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your config contains:
`"jsonlines_embedding_format":stringToBool(std.extVar('jsonlines_embedding_format'))}`

which is trying to read an environment variable named `jsonlines_embedding_format` and convert it to a boolean value.

The error says that the environment variable is not defined, so you need to define it first, before calling the train command.